# Large holes by the fence, which animal would be digging such holes in Northern California?

Tags: wildlife, digging, squirrel, redwood

I've noticed two large holes under our [three giant redwoods](https://youtu.be/ml35xfnPF_0?si=B185TBAc3DUQZg3Y). We have many squirrels and I'm thinking they did that, but those holes look really large so I'm wondering whether squirrels do indeed dig such large holes. I've not seen droppings or caught anyone around the holes (so far). They are hidden from my view point from within the house and they can hear if I walk toward the location.

I've taken a few pictures to show how large these are. Where I grew up, Eastern France, these would be rabbit holes. I don't think we have rabbits, however, we do have skunks and raccoons (although I don't think raccoons would venture this far, over 1 mile, from the river side or parks) and large black rats in the area. But I've see rat holes that look much more like mole holes and these are not the same at all.

[image: Southern hole, shot 1]
[image: Southern hole, shot 2]
[image: Southern hole, inside view]
[image: Northern hole]
[image: Northern hole, close up]
[image: Northern hole, inside view]
[image: Northern hole with hand to show size better]

Comment: Looks very much like woodchuck holes to me - especially the hole in the last three photos -  but woodchucks are not supposed to be in California. If you have or know someone who has a trailcam, I'd recommend setting it up near the hole that goes under that raised bed. If they ARE chucks who've decided to see the sights in No. Cal, you'll see them at night.

Comment: Rodents, yes. Sprinkle ground black pepper, ground ginger, or mustard powder there periodically. All mammals can smell, and will avoid it. Or used and stinky cat litter.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Oh. We have free cat litter at hand! :)

Comment: At this point in the 21st century "what animal" is generally a matter of setting up some now-obsolete device (cell phone, tablet, computer, actual camera as camera) that has a video camera (or multiple still capability) (using the obsolete one so you don't mind parking it outside to record for some hours) and seeing what the critter is, unless you actually want to spend money on a non-obsolete device to do that...

Answer (score 0):

Could possibly be an opossum? You can attach some wire fencing at base, like chicken wire to prevent further digging.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi teaves, I decided to get a camera that takes pictures when it detects something moving. I'll be able to see soon. I'll giving it a week for a better chance to see what it is. But an opossum, it could be. These do go much further away from the park and it's probably about the right size.

Comment: Im curious to see what you discover

Comment: So far, nothing that would dig those holes... I have a [slideshow](https://youtu.be/qjEU4R4dD8Q?si=z60khwBKLtm6CMOx) with last week critters.

Comment: Never know what nature will reveal on a game camera